# Unable to install apache2 through apt

Tags: apt, apache2

I'm trying to install apache2 on an Ubuntu server 18.04.

While trying to install it using apt, I seem to be stuck.

Following step keeps repeating and eventually the process never end.

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
86% [1 apache2-data 9874 B/160 kB 6%]^C
```

Full output:

```
sudo apt install apache2 -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  formencode-i18n ieee-data landscape-hashids landscape-server libjs-yui3-common libjs-yui3-full libjs-yui3-min python-amqp
  python-amqplib python-bson python-bson-ext python-chameleon python-convoy python-crypto python-cssutils python-dateutil
  python-dbus python-decorator python-dnspython python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-epsilon python-extras
  python-fake-factory python-fixtures python-formencode python-gi python-gnupg python-iso8601 python-keyring python-keyrings.alt
  python-launchpadlib python-linecache2 python-mechanize python-mimeparse python-netaddr python-oops python-oops-amqp
  python-oops-datedir-repo python-oops-twisted python-oops-wsgi python-openid python-paste python-pastedeploy
  python-pastedeploy-tpl python-pastescript python-pbr python-persistent python-prometheus-client python-psycopg2 python-pycurl
  python-restrictedpython python-scgi python-secretstorage python-storm python-stripe python-tempita python-testtools
  python-traceback2 python-transaction python-treq python-txamqp python-txaws python-txjuju python-txlongpoll python-tz
  python-unidecode python-unittest2 python-venusian python-vine python-waitress python-webob python-webtest python-yaml python-z3c
  python-z3c.pt python-zc python-zc.lockfile python-zconfig python-zdaemon python-zodb python-zope.annotation
  python-zope.app.appsetup python-zope.app.http python-zope.app.pagetemplate python-zope.app.publication python-zope.app.schema
  python-zope.app.wsgi python-zope.authentication python-zope.broken python-zope.browser python-zope.browsermenu
  python-zope.browserpage python-zope.browserresource python-zope.cachedescriptors python-zope.component python-zope.component-zcml
  python-zope.configuration python-zope.container python-zope.contentprovider python-zope.contenttype python-zope.datetime
  python-zope.dottedname python-zope.dublincore python-zope.error python-zope.event python-zope.exceptions
  python-zope.filerepresentation python-zope.formlib python-zope.hookable python-zope.i18n python-zope.i18nmessageid
  python-zope.lifecycleevent python-zope.location python-zope.minmax python-zope.pagetemplate python-zope.password
  python-zope.pluggableauth python-zope.principalregistry python-zope.processlifetime python-zope.proxy python-zope.publisher
  python-zope.schema python-zope.security python-zope.securitypolicy python-zope.sendmail python-zope.session python-zope.site
  python-zope.size python-zope.tal python-zope.tales python-zope.testbrowser python-zope.testing python-zope.traversing
  python-zope.untrustedpython python-zope.viewlet
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
Suggested packages:
  www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 160 kB/1410 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5893 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.26 [160 kB]
86% [1 apache2-data 9874 B/160 kB 6%]^C
```

I'm only using Ubuntu in my homelab, no quite experienced.
Is there something I can do about this?
Trying to install apache2 as part of the configuration for Landscape.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a weird error. Since 18.04 will be out of support in 3 weeks, I'd suggest upgrading first. It's unlikely that you'll still see the error afterwards.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback! From what I understand, Landscape isn't supported yet on any other versions of Ubuntu.

https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem

System Requirements

The operating system must be Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS x86_64 for Landscape Server. PostgreSQL may be run on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS, or 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Found it! My local firewall was blocking the file download (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.14_all.deb) due to being unable to scan it :)